# The restricted direct product is a normal subgroup of the direct product

Tags: group-theory

Let $G =\prod _{i \in I} G_i $ be the product of $G_i (i \in I).$ Let $ H= \{f \in \prod G_i: f(i) = e_i \text{ for all finite many  element of I} \rbrace$.

Show that $H\lhd G $

I am genuinely don't how to proof this. Would I have  deal with multiple cases i.e 
When all the elements of $H$ are the identity 
and none of them are the identity.

Any tips and hints will be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint-Proof:

$$\forall\,g\in G\;,\;\forall\,f\in H\;\;,\;\;g^{-1}fg(i)=e_i\;\;\text{for all but a finite number of}\;\;i\;\ldots$$

Comment: Why does that help? Would elements of $H$ look like $( e_1,..,e_r , g)$?

Comment: What's the definition of **normal** subgroup, @Matthew ?

Comment: @Matthew A subgroup  $H$ is normal iff $\forall h \in H : \forall g \in G  $  $ghg^{-1} \in H$

Comment: There you go...:) !

Comment: Ahh! whatever the remaining elements are is irrelevant.

Comment: $g(i)$ would be element in the ith position of g?

Comment: As **you** wrote it, every element $\;f\in\prod G_i\;$ is a function $\;f\;$ on an index set $\;I\;$ s.t. $\;\forall\,i\in I\;,\;\;f(i)\in G_i\;$.

The product here is pointwise: $\;fg(i):=f(i)g(i)\;\;\forall\,i\in I\;$, and the inverse is $\;g^{-1}(i):=g(i)^{-1}\;$

Thus, $g^{-1}fg(i)=g(i)^{-1}f(i)g(i)$, and no matter what $\;g\;$ does, at all but a finite number of indexes we have $\;f(i)=e_i:=$the unity element in $\;G_i\;$ , so $$g(i)=x_i\in G_i\implies g(i)^{-1}f(i)g(i)=x_i^{-1}f(i)x_i$$and since $\;f(i)$ for almost all indexes, the above is $\;e_i\;$ for almost all indexes